# Proving that Cauchy Summation converges

Tags: calculus, summation, cauchy-sequences

How can I prove that the following summation converges?
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{(-1)^n}{(k+1)\times (n-k+1)}$$

I tried to prove that by proving that the following summation in in absolute value converges so the original one converges too, but that's incorrect.

Any other ideas?

**Note:** I found that **if it converges** then it converges to ln(2)^2 but that doesn't help since I want to prove the it converges at first place.

Comment: I see you have now asked exactly the same question three times! Please stop doing this. I hope that some moderator will be able to merge the questions somehow.

Comment: A duplicate of [the OP's] [Proving that $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{(-1)^n}{(k+1)\times (n-k+1)}$ converges](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3684312/proving-that-sum-n-0-infty-sum-k-0n-frac-1nk1-times-n-k1)